# Gmail push notifications Python API

Tags: python, ssl, push-notification, webserver, gmail-api

I'm trying to get new messages on my Gmail account via push notifications API.
I have a server with ssl certificate that I already verified in Google as mine and add to my Pub/Sub project:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import http.server
import array
import ssl

class CallbackHTTPServer(http.server.HTTPServer):
    def server_activate(self):
        http.server.HTTPServer.server_activate(self)


class HttpProcessor(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def add_OK_plain_text_header(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('content-type','text/plain')
        self.end_headers()


    def do_GET(self):
        self.add_OK_plain_text_header()
        print("GOT GET REQUEST")
        self.wfile.write("OK".encode('utf-8'))


    def do_POST(self):
        self.add_OK_plain_text_header()
        print("GOT POST REQUEST")
        self.wfile.write("OK".encode('utf-8'))


def main():
    httpd = CallbackHTTPServer(('', 443), HttpProcessor)
    httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket(httpd.socket, certfile='./server.pem', server_side=True)
    httpd.serve_forever()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I also created a topic and a subscription for push notifications to my server address (as described in [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-console)).
I also initialized Gmail API as described in [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) and have ran Gmail API watch request that responded with correct historyId and expiration.
But my server doesn't get any updates even when I create them manually by publishing message to my topic:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import os

from apiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import tools
from oauth2client.file import Storage

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

# If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
# at ~/.credentials/gmail-python-quickstart.json
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Gmail API Python Quickstart'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'gmail-python-quickstart.json')

    store = Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else: # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials

def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    service = discovery.build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)

    request = {
      'labelIds': ['INBOX'],
      'topicName': 'projects/################/topics/#######'
    }
    print(service.users().watch(userId='me', body=request).execute())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Check if you have granted Gmail privileges to publish notifications to your topic, Cloud Pub/Sub requires it. Also double check every steps in this [document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push), to see if you have missed anything. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I granted privileges to publish notifications to Gmail.
I've done all the steps of the document you give.

Answer (score 2):

Have you grant Grant publish rights on your topic yet?
[check out this link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push)

or read this:

> Grant publish rights on your topic Cloud Pub/Sub requires that you
>   grant Gmail privileges to publish notifications to your topic.
>
> To do this, you need to grant publish privileges to
>   `serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`. You can do
>   this using the Cloud Pub/Sub Developer Console permissions interface
>   following the resource-level access control instructions.